# how to run `php artisan queue:work` every minute on cpanel?

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-queue, laravel-scheduler

I made an cronjob in cpanel for once per minute like this:

[image]

and make a command for that like this:

[image]

as you see I give the artisan path to that.

and in this path :/home/{projcetname}/laravel/app/Console/Kernel.php
I wrote the commands.

but queue table is full.

how can I run `queue:work` for always ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an entry in your kernel.php that regularly starts a queue worker with the  --stop-when-empty flag.  I wrote this technique up a little while back and have used it effectively on several sites https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/using-queues-on-shared-hosting-with-laravel

Comment: I followed the instructions. it does not work for me !
where to paste` * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/{account_name}/live/artisan schedule:run` ?

Comment: @arefrazaviyou already did this step in yout original question

Answer (score 2):

How you can run queue:work is the same of how you ran schedule run, Just define a new cron job

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/sabbabecom/laravel/artisan queue:work --once >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But when you say always, Does it mean like you want to run it every time it finishes with the current job. If that so then you need to have a supervisor otherwise you can just use the approach i've wrote and it should works fine. At least that what i've understood from your question.

Comment: The flaw with this approach is that it can only perform one job per minute (due to --once).  If you generate more than 60 jobs per hour, the queue will never empty or will have significant delays.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was about php version
I change the php command to this and it's work:

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php81
```